# PayPal, Payflow Pro

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout, payflowpro

Here is the complete situation:

- Site running with Express checkout and normal checkout of PayPal

Now if the customer orders with PayPal in a normal way. Means first take login (if not) gives your full information for shipping etc, and then go to PayPal site to pay and complete your order.

Is it possible to do a reference transaction of that order using [Payflow Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/home) (keep in mind I complete the order using PayPal)? Or do we have to use another way?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you haven't posted example code, and the commercial product you need help with is supported by the vendor.  Perhaps you should ask your vendor?

Comment: Hi Ghoti Thanks for taking interest.
Let me explain it in a simple way.  
    My Client want to use his customer Credit Card information for Paypal refrence transaction.
          Example : Customer "A" buy Product "X". Now after somedays the Customer "A" called to the client that please shipped another one more piece of product "X" and billed from my Credit CArd (keep in mind we didn't have his credit card password).
        Now in this situation my Client want to Enter his credit CArd number and do a refrence transaction.